# " error: unknown field ‘compat_ioctl’ specified in initializer " while creating dummy ioctl

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module, ioctl

static const struct inode_operations msdos_dir_inode_operations = {

```
.create     = msdos_create,
.lookup     = msdos_lookup,
.unlink     = msdos_unlink,
.mkdir      = msdos_mkdir,
.rmdir      = msdos_rmdir,
.rename     = msdos_rename,
.setattr    = fat_setattr,
.getattr    = fat_getattr,
.compat_ioctl   = my_ioctl,   ---->error
```

};

i also tried with unlocked_ioctl but same error occured

[root@localhost fat]# make

make -C /lib/modules/3.11.10-100.fc18.x86_64/build M=/home/aditya/linux-3.12.6/fs/fat modules

make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.11.10-100.fc18.x86_64'
  CC [M]  /home/aditya/linux-3.12.6/fs/fat/namei_msdos.o

/home/aditya/linux-3.12.6/fs/fat/namei_msdos.c:646:2: error: unknown field ‘compat_ioctl’ specified in initializer

/home/aditya/linux-3.12.6/fs/fat/namei_msdos.c:646:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/home/aditya/linux-3.12.6/fs/fat/namei_msdos.c:646:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘msdos_dir_inode_operations.setxattr’) [enabled by default]
make[2]: *** [/home/aditya/linux-3.12.6/fs/fat/namei_msdos.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [*module*/home/aditya/linux-3.12.6/fs/fat] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.11.10-100.fc18.x86_64'
make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: As far as I can see, [`struct inode_operations`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/fs.h?v=3.12#L1557) does not have `*_ioctl` fields in 3.12. These callbacks are from `struct file_operations`, did you intend to use that instead?

Comment: yes but i have modified fs.h and added
int (*unlocked_ioctl) (struct file *,unsigned int , unsigned long);
}
in struct inode_operations ...
then also it showing the same error

Comment: hey please help for previous comment

Comment: You added `unlocked_ioctl` but the code above uses `compat_ioctl`, this may be the cause of the error. Anyway, the complete solution depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

The ioctl has been changed for a reason and it would be best if you follow the kernel changes in your driver too.  You can not use drivers compiled for one version in another. 
The change is not too difficult one.

In the fops structure change

`ioctl` to `unlocked_ioctl`

and in the ioctl function in your driver, do not pass the `inode` pointer. That is all, the rest of the code can remain the same.

see [this tutorial](http://tuxthink.blogspot.in/2012/12/implementing-ioctl-call-for-kernel.html)  for more details